# css grid-row and grid-column

Tags: css, css-grid

Hi I'm learning css grid but I can't undertand this result.
I use the class span-row-3 with grid-row: span 3; 
when I use it alone it works like for item 1
but when I use it with a span-col-3 it didn't work anymore like in Item 6

Is there any reason why my grid-row: span 3; isn't working here

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.span-col-3{grid-column: span 3;}

.span-row-3{grid-row: span 3;}
.grid div {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: .8rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #302742;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff4d;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    color: #ffffff80;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="span-row-3">Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div class="span-col-3 span-row-3">Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div>Item 8</div>
  <div>Item 9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works fine - the problem is your rows do not have equal height.
Set `grid-auto-rows` to specify the size of grid-row:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.span-col-3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.span-row-3 {
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.grid div {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: .8rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #302742;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff4d;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  color: #ffffff80;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="span-row-3">Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div class="span-col-3 span-row-3">Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div>Item 8</div>
  <div>Item 9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out "span-col-3" for item1

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.span-col-3{grid-column: span 3;}

.span-row-3{grid-row: span 3;}
.grid div {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: .8rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #302742;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff4d;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    color: #ffffff80;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="span-col-3 span-row-3">Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div class="span-col-3 span-row-3">Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div>Item 8</div>
  <div>Item 9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `grid-auto-rows` is set to `auto`, by default.

With `auto`, grid items are sized [*relative to other items in the same track*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-grid-template-columns-auto).

Item1 shares two rows with other items.

Item6 doesn't share the row with any other item.

Hence, their `auto` sizes are different.

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50704858/3597276), defining a length on `grid-auto-rows` resolves the problem. There may be other methods.